# NUnit: Is it possible to configure NUnit that a Test fails, if no Assert has executed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/). Is it possible to configure NUnit in a way, so that every UnitTest fails that does not call at least once an Assert-Method?

So I can prevent some cases of invalid UnitTests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/QhTGEQjcX-k) it does not appear to be possible. Admittedly this is from 3 years ago but I do not think the answer has changed.

> Stated simply, there's no setting such as you are looking for. I 
>   recall that we discussed the possibility a long time ago on the old 
>   SourceForge mailing list and that the general opinion at the time was 
>   for an empty test to simply succeed. One reason is that some people 
>   were writing tests in which all the Asserts were conditional and 
>   *didn't* want to see a failure if none were applicable. Of course, the  biggest reason is that NUnit is oriented toward TDD, even if not 
>   exclusively. So the general community of users does not usually have a
>   bunch of empty tests.

A ['bug'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/1216527) was created for adding support for a command line option to enable this feature but it does not appear to have any activity since 2013. I cannot see any corresponding issue on the nUnit Github though.

Comment: I can confirm that we haven't implemented that functionality. Shouldn't invalid unit tests be caught in code reviews? :)

Comment: I deliberately didn't carry that forward from SF.A variation of the request is to fail if no code is executed. That would take an inordinate amount of work for what seems to be a "niche" market.